# What graphical toolkits exist with "good" Ruby bindings?

Tags: ruby, graphics, user-interface, toolkit

I want to create a tool with Ruby which works with all 3 of the major OSes (Windows, Linux, Mac OS X). What choices do I have for toolkits where the bindings for Ruby is "good"? By good I mean not just quick direct mapping of the C/C++ API onto Ruby, for instance using blocks where appropriate and other Ruby features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say QTRuby (so bindings for QT) seem to be the most advanced and also quite cross platform without requiring some pre-installed virtual machine - like in the case of Ruby (JRuby Java Swing Bridge - another very good solution if the user already has Swing know-how)

Answer (score 0):

Until recently, pretty much the best options were Swing and SWT. And you know that there is something seriously wrong if Swing is your best option. But now, there's also WPF.

All three, Swing, SWT and WPF work great on Windows, OSX, Linux and probably a dozen others.

Answer (score 0):

For OS X I would say MacRuby - http://www.macruby.org/ because of HotCocoa http://www.macruby.org/hotcocoa.html

Answer (score 0):

By far the most thoroughly supported is Tk (Ruby/Tk: http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/ext_tk.html), and it'll run on just about anything. Down side is, it isn't very pretty.

Here's another good guide for using Ruby/Tk: _http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_tk_guide.htm

If you're looking for something a little nicer looking, try gtk(2): _http://ruby-gnome2.sourceforge.jp/hiki.cgi?tut-gtk